# Is there an alternative way instead of increasing the number of plotpoints in RegionPlot to get a better result?

Tags: plotting, functions, precision-and-accuracy

I have this function and I use RegionPlot to see in which part of the domain, the function is negative:

```
f := 1/4 x^2 Sinh[(2 \[Pi] x)/
     3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 (-512 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] + 
      128 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] + 64 Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
      32 x^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 4 x^4 Sinh[\[Pi] x] - 
      128 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 64 x^2 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      8 x^4 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] + 576 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      96 x^2 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 4 x^4 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3])^2 - 
   4 (256 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 128 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
      16 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
      256 x^2 Sinh[(2 \[Pi] x)/
        3]^2) Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 (64 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
      32 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 4 x^4 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
      16 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] - 
      4 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
      x^4 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
      1/4 x^6 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
      x^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 3/8 x^4 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
      1/16 x^6 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 1/256 x^8 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
      256 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
      128 x^2 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - 
      16 x^4 Cosh[(2 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 + 
      32 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      8 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      2 x^4 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      1/2 x^6 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      4 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      4 x^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      3/2 x^4 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      1/4 x^6 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      1/64 x^8 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      4 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 4 x^2 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
      3/2 x^4 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 1/4 x^6 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
      1/64 x^8 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
      144 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      60 x^2 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      7 x^4 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      1/4 x^6 Sinh[(\[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      18 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      6 x^2 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      1/4 x^4 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      1/8 x^6 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      1/128 x^8 Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      36 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      12 x^2 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      1/2 x^4 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      1/4 x^6 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] - 
      1/64 x^8 Sinh[(5 \[Pi] x)/3] Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3] + 
      81 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 27 x^2 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
      27/8 x^4 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 - 
      3/16 x^6 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2 + 
      1/256 x^8 Sinh[(7 \[Pi] x)/3]^2);
RegionPlot[a f < 0, {x, 3.46572, 3.46574}, {a, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60]
```

This is the result:

[image]

I am sure that the blue part should be a continuous domain. How can I get a better result? Is there an alternative way instead of increasing the number of plotpoints? Since it is not easy for my system and it takes much time.

Comment: You mention `ContourPlot` in the title and text but it is `RegionPlot` in the code.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. I meant RegionPlot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` can be simplified (and I would use `=` rather than `:=`):

```
f = FullSimplify[f]
(*  -2 (-4 + x^2)^2 (1 + Cosh[(2 π x)/3] + 
   Cosh[(4 π x)/3])^2 (155392 - 153856 x^2 + 8608 x^4 - 144 x^6 - 
   x^8 - 256 (-6 + x) (6 + x) (32 - 28 x^2 + x^4) Cosh[(2 π x)/3] - 
   64 (-3776 + 2768 x^2 - 212 x^4 + 3 x^6) Cosh[(4 π x)/3] - 
   64 (-12 + x^2) (208 - 96 x^2 + 3 x^4) Cosh[2 π x] - 
   128 (-12 + x^2)^2 (-4 + x^2) Cosh[(8 π x)/3] +
   (-12 + x^2)^4 Cosh[(10 π x)/3]) Sinh[(π x)/3]^6 *)
```

Then a plot of `f` over an appropriate range shows where `f` is negative:

```
Plot[f, {x, Rationalize[3.46572838, 0], Rationalize[3.46572842, 0]}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image: Plot of f vs x where f is generally negative]

Now the `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[a f < 0, {x, Rationalize[3.46572838, 0], Rationalize[3.46572842, 0]}, {a, 0, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 60, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image: Region plot]

So you end up with a rectangle.  Am I missing something?  (Yes, the display of the horizontal axis tick mark labels needs work.)

If it is a `ContourPlot` that you want, then the following might work:

```
ContourPlot[a f, {x, Rationalize[3.46572838, 0], Rationalize[3.46572842, 0]}, {a, 0, 1},
 Contours -> 10^22 Range[-10, 0], PlotPoints -> 60, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, FrameLabel -> {"x", "a"},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer.  But I do not understand how you obtained these values $[3.46572838, 0], [3.46572842, 0]$? And also about the last part in ContourPlot, why did you choose the range $[-10,0]$?

Comment: Trial and error.  I first plotted `f` with `Plot[f, {x, 3.46572, 3.46574}, PlotPoints -> 60]` and then zeroed in on the values of `x` that were near zero.  The range that showed the negative values (which `a f < 0` would still always be negative as `a >= 0`) was chosen for the range of `x`.  Then I used the range of negative values of `f` to obtain `10^22 Range[-10,0]`.

Comment: To find where `f` is **nonpositive** use [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html): `FunctionDomain[Sqrt[-f], x]`